# Xcode 3.2.1 - Symbol / Documentation lookup is failing based on mystery plugin/preference

Tags: iphone, xcode

Since upgrading to Xcode 3.2.1, I've experienced a strange issue that has really killed my workflow. The issue only exhibits itself under my own user account (the same project opened by a different user works fine). Therefore, the heart of this question is, "what does Xcode load from the user directory that could conceivably cause this issue?"

(System: Snow Leopard 10.6.1; Xcode 3.2.1 w/ iPhone SDK 3.1.2)

Symptoms:

- Code completion only works on symbols of the current class or already referenced in the class. Virtually useless.
- Document/reference lookups (i.e. option-double-clicking on an identifier or symbol returns this strange result): "Documentation not found for the symbol '`symbol name`'. Click here to view symbol declaration."

Like I said, since other users are experiencing normal behavior in Xcode, this must be due to something only loaded for my user account. I've already eliminated `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist`, `~/Application Support/Developer,`~/Application Support/Xcode`.

The only thing I've recently installed is [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.com/code/mogenerator) (the defunct xmod integration may have killed it, but it doesn't install anything to the user directory)

*Update: 10/26/09*
This one is really starting to kill me. I did a fresh OS X install, followed by an Xcode 3.2 install from the Leopard disc, followed by an iPhone SDK install from the ADC site, and this started occurring again within 30 minutes of my having started working. I'm at an utter loss. The error is most obvious when option-double-clicking on a symbol (say, the `NSString` class) and instead of getting the documentation snippet, a message "Cannot determine the symbol for the current selection." appears.

*Update: 10/26/09 #2*
I just tried creating a fresh project, and that project's symbols are appearing fine. So the issue is apparently local to my project. Hopefully that's a better start. To demonstrate what I'm talking about, here's a screen of the issue manifesting itself with respect to documentation:

[image: Screen shot of the issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding your CodeSense index? Project > Edit Project Settings > General >

[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Rebuild.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/Rebuild.png)

After doing that, check Console.app to see if Xcode issued any warnings.  It's possible that some of your source code causes the indexer to stop, and you don't end up with a valid index. Filing a bug with Apple and providing the source, if possible, would help Apple fix problems like this.

Comment: The console message embedded in this gist [ http://gist.github.com/219140 ] occurs the first time Xcode launches the project in question. Any chance you could help decode this? (You're so close to winning the bounty, after all!)

Comment: After reading the gist more closely, it looked like the static analyzer was causing the indexing issue--turning off the Static Analysis execution restored the symbols!

I really want to use static analysis, however; I wonder how/why this would be occurring.

Comment: I'm going to just give it to you. if you can comment if you have further ideas, I'd appreciate it, but your solution got me CodeSense back (even if it's at the cost of clang).

For those interested, I opened a bug report with Apple, as suggested. Open Radar duplicate is: http://openradar.appspot.com/7338181

Answer (score 2):

This is the first thing I'd try:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20091026-ek3id5s121wqrsiu8apwm4qgir.png](http://img.skitch.com/20091026-ek3id5s121wqrsiu8apwm4qgir.png)

Wait until it doesn't say "Getting" anywhere anymore before doing anything documentation related.

Answer (score 2):

Given the clues from the console:

```
10/26/09 7:21:58 PM Xcode[19072]    Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'clang' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'objective-c'.  This may lead to indexing issues.
Compiler: /Developer/usr/bin/clang
Reason:   clang version 1.0.1 (http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/tags/Apple/clang-24 exported)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10
clang: warning: not using the clang compiler for the 'armv6' architecture
```

I'm going to say that you tried to configure an iPhone Device build to use the Clang compiler, which is not yet supported for compilation.  (It works for static analysis, but not for building).

Find the Compiler Version build setting and set it back to gcc 4.2.

Comment: It's all coming back to me now. I remember this from the release notes; it just totally slipped my mind once I actually started debugging a new app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I was able to workaround it by:

1. Setting the target to be the iPhone simulator
2. Quit and relaunch Xcode
3. Rebuild the index
4. Clean and rebuild the simulator target

Maybe it's a bug in Xcode with iPhone device selected when a project is first opened.