# Error when building using xcodebuild

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I have an xcode Objective-C iPhone static library project. When I build it in xcode I get no errors or warnings. But when I build it using xcodebuild from the command line I get:

```
"/Developer/usr/bin/gcc" -v -dM -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk -E -arch armv6 -o - -x objective-c /dev/null
gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I cannot find anything that helps me to understand what the issue is, any ideas?

And yes the /Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 file does exist :-)

Comment: You should probably post the xcodebuild command line too, so that we can see the arguments etc that you are passing to it.

Comment: I had it in a command shell target in xcode. I've just tried it from a command shell and it didn't produce the error. So I think it's something to do with running it from within Xcode.

Comment: Nope, getting it in xcode as well now. Oh hang a sec, now it's gone, GRRR!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason what seemed to fix this for me is actually passing in the architectures to be used.

For instance, this command fails:

```
/Developer-SDK4/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target ProjectName -configuration Release build PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator BUILDSDK=/Developer-SDK4
```

But this one works:

```
/Developer-SDK4/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target ProjectName -configuration Release build PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator BUILDSDK=/Developer-SDK4 ARCHS=i386
```

Note, this only failed for me when building against the simulator.  Building against the device seemed to work just fine.

Comment: For the record, I had also tried the steps outlined in these pages:

http://openradar.appspot.com/7338181

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598502/xcode-3-2-1-symbol-documentation-lookup-is-failing-based-on-mystery-plugin-pr

Comment: Tried adding the architectures, but no luck. Still getting the errors even though everything works.

Comment: Adding `ARCHS=x86_64` worked for me in 2023, seems like this question is older, but it still lead me to the solution